# iPad simulator showing black screen on the left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

[image]

Hi, I'm making an iPhone/iPad app. However in the iPad simulator the screen is showing black screen on the left for no apparent reasons. I launched the app with iPhone simulator and it works fine.

Here are some of the things I did:

1. The orientation is landscape mode. It is set under General settings with landscape left and landscape right checked. It is also set to landscape in the iPad storyboard view controller Orientation.
2. There is a navigation controller and on top is the main view controller. So I suppose the black screen is the navigation controller if not mistaken.

Does anyone has any idea on what went wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You designed a UI for the iphone which has a much smaller screen than the ipad and thus it "feels in the gaps" with black. Use the layout tools to make your view spread to the entire screen automatically to fix this.

EDIT:

[Here are some useful tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[that I used to get me started on auto layout](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Comment: Nevermind, this is apparently a bug with xcode or the simulator. I did enable auto layout. When I launch it with my iPad. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, when launching the app on the iPad device. It works fine.